# Подключение статической библиотеки к проекту на С++ без использования Visual Studio, а чистым компилятором gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

Файл библиотеки

test2.cpp

```
#include <test2.h> 
int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Заголовочный файл
test2.h

```
int add(int, int);
```

файл проекта
test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lib/test2.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<add(1,2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Компилирую при помощи gcc
test.bat

```
g++ -E  test.cpp  -o test.ii
g++ -S test.ii -o test.s
as test.s -o test.o
g++ test.o -o test
```

И мне выдаёт ошибку

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\C++\test>g++ test.o -o test
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `add(int, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Расположение файлов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ¿Не смущает, что `test2.cpp` при сборке никак не используется? ¿Или что упомянутой статической библиотеки нет?

Comment: В чем прикол делать препроцессинг и компиляцию в ассемблер отдельными командами? Можно сразу `g++ test.cpp -c -o test.o`.